# what to keep in node_modules after react-native init?

Tags: dependencies, react-native, setup-project, init, node-modules

When I do a react-native init  I get a node_modules directory full of 587 packages!

The `package.json` file only has a total of 35 entries for both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

Can any of these packages be cleaned up? Do I need to keep all of them in order for my application to work?